# How to test $resource calls if it contains specific headers on making http request?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, tdd, angularjs-ng-resource

I have this following factory.

```
services.factory('Api', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

        return $resource(urlPath, {
            'action': 'get',
            'entity': 'Entity'
        }, {
          MakePost: {
            method: "POST",
            isArray: false,
            headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
              var str = [];

              for (var p in obj) {
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
              }

              return str.join("&");
            }
          }
        }
      );
    }]);
```

Now, i would like to test, when calling `Api.MakePost({},{data: {}}, function () {})` the correct header data i.e in this case `'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` is set correctly. Is there away to test this scenario in angularjs, using $httpBackend, Jasmine and spies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be tested in two different ways, with unit and functional tests.

When compared with `$http`, `$resource` contains more moving parts, and it makes sense to stub it - at least for some tests.

```
beforeEach(module('app'))
...
describe('$resource is stubbed in this block', () => {
  var resourceObjStub;
  var resourceFactoryStub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    resourceObjStub = jasmine.createSpyObj(['MakePost']);
    resourceFactoryStub = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(resourceObjStub);

    module({ $resource: resourceFactoryStub });
  });

  it('...', inject((Api) => {
    expect(resourceFactoryStub).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      ...
      {...},
      { MakePost: {
        headers: {...},
        transformRequest: jasmine.any(Function),
        ...
      } }
    );
    expect(Api).toBe(resourceObjStub);
  });
});
```

Then provided `$resource` arguments can be tested more thoroughly, e.g. `transformRequest` method can be reached with `resourceFactoryStub.calls.first()[2].transformRequest` and tested directly.

Or the whole thing can be tested in another test with `$httpBackend` and real `$resource`.